# advanced cycle usage?

Tags: ruby, jekyll, liquid

I'm trying to figure out how to used Liquid's `cycle` with the html blelow appropriately. It's a never-ending row, 3-column max (`float:left`) layout.

```
<!-- row -->
<div class="single-post-container">
   <div class="single-post-item">
      <div class="single-post-head">
         <a href="{{ post.url }}" />
         <h6>{{ post.title }}</h6>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="single-post-item">
      <div class="single-post-head">
         <a href="{{ post.url }}" />
         <h6>{{ post.title }}</h6>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="single-post-item">
      <div class="single-post-head">
         <a href="{{ post.url }}" />
         <h6>{{ post.title }}</h6>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<!-- row -->
<div class="single-post-container">
   <div class="single-post-item">
      <div class="single-post-head">
         <a href="{{ post.url }}" />
         <h6>{{ post.title }}</h6>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="single-post-item">
      <div class="single-post-head">
         <a href="{{ post.url }}" />
         <h6>{{ post.title }}</h6>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="single-post-item">
      <div class="single-post-head">
         <a href="{{ post.url }}" />
         <h6>{{ post.title }}</h6>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I was able to get it half-working (`{{ post.title }}` literally shows up instead of the actual title) with this ugly thing:

```
{% for post in site.posts %}

   column {%cycle '<div class="single-post-container"><div class="single-post-item"><div class="single-post-head"><a href="{{ post.url }}" /><h6>{{ post.title }}</h6></div></div>', '<div class="single-post-item"><div class="single-post-head"><a href="{{ post.url }}" /><h6>{{ post.title }}</h6></div></div>', '<div class="single-post-item"><div class="single-post-head"><a href="{{ post.url }}" /><h6>{{ post.title }}</h6></div></div></div>'%}

{% endfor %}
```

Please help! Maybe there is a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strings in the `cycle` tag aren't processed, so the liquid substitutions don't happen (which is why `{{ post.title }}` is there literally).

A better approach might be something like:

```
{% for post in site.posts %}
  {% cycle '<div class="single-post-container">', '', '' %}
  <div class="single-post-item">
    <div class="single-post-head">
      <a href="{{ post.url }}" />
      <h6>{{ post.title }}</h6>
    </div>
  </div>
  {% cycle '', '', '</div> %}
{% endfor %}
```

which cycles just the opening and closing tags. Note that this breaks (leaves a `div` open) if the number of posts is not a multiple of 3.

An even better solution, based on the above, might be:

```
{% for post in site.posts %}
  {% capture mod_three %}{{ forloop.index0 | modulo: 3 }}{% endcapture %}
  {% if mod_three == '0' %}
    <div class="single-post-container">
  {% endif %}
      <div class="single-post-item">
        <div class="single-post-head">
          <a href="{{ post.url }}" />
          <h6>{{ post.title }}</h6>
        </div>
     </div>
  {% if mod_three == '2' or forloop.last %}
     </div>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

This (in theory, I haven't tested it yet) will not leave the div open if the number of posts is not a multiple of 3 (that's what the `or forloop.last` is testing for).

([Here is some documentation](http://wiki.shopify.com/UsingLiquid#For_loops) about the special `forloop` variable and its attributes.)